# COUNTIF is 0. Two values in the same column

Tags: microsoft-excel, countif

It seems that my formula is not counting 2 different values in the same column. The only calculation that worked was one with identical values.

Can you share a method to associate multiple values to the same "label"? My plan is to use SUMIF using the label values later on..

```
=COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,A15,$A$2:$A$12,B15,$B$2:$B$12,"Yes")
```

- A15= {Label}
- ​B15= {Department}

Comment: SUMPRODUCT can get the result.

Answer (score 2):

COUNTIF are AND statements, in that you are expecting the values in A to be equal to A15 AND B15 at the same time, which it can't.

Instead use and array and SUMPRODUCT:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIFS($A$2:$A$12,A15:B15,$B$2:$B$12,"Yes"))
```

It will now do two separate COUNTIFS() one counting where it is equal to A15 and one where it is equal to B15 and then sum the results.

Note:  With Office 365 `SUMPRODUCT` can be substituted with `SUM`